# Why am I not growing muscularly?

Tags: weightlifting, strength, bodybuilding, strength-training

I have been weightlifting for sometime but my muscles are not growing as much as I would like.

My workout plan consist of daily light weightlifting and some cardio excerise.
And my diet is traditional Indian diet.

But still i have not developed muscles at all.

Comment: Your question as it stands is a duplicate, but if you edit it to include your diet and workout plan, and ask more along the lines of "Why is this not working" instead of focusing on T levels, it can be nominated for reopening.

Comment: Okay i have added my diet and workout plan.

Comment: I've edited your question to remove the testosterone question and re-opened it, it's still pretty vague, so expect some people to ask for more detail (Such as what you actually do for light weightlifting, and what "some cardio" means) before they answer. I would suggest you read the help section as well.

Comment: How long have you been lifting? Which lifts? Weights? Body weight? Height? Age? How much protein is consumed daily?

Comment: I am lifting for 2 months and Weights are usually between 10 to 15 kgs, and im 18 years old height is approx 170 cm. And i have no idea how much protein i consume but i am fat, my weight is 82.5 kg.

Comment: Are you gaining weight at all , just worried it's fast or maintaining?

Comment: Besides nutrition, here's another post that gives some insight on how to train http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/8239/20256

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> light weightlifting

This will not build muscle for you. Lift heavier weights.

> some cardio excerise

This fights your effort to gain muscle. Consider doing less cardio if you want to grow muscle.

> traditional Indian diet

You're not giving much detail here, but more food, particularly more protein, would almost certainly help.

To recap: to grow muscle, you need to lift heavier weights, stop doing stuff that doesn't help, and eat more.

Comment: Based on my knowledge, the Indian diet is carb-heavy. Might be worth mentioning that the importance of using a tape measure to check progress rather than relying on a mirror.

Comment: Wow! This is the fastest I've seen anyone take some advice, pack on muscle, and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather vague, but there are a few potential reasons you aren't gaining muscle.  Remember, these are only possibilities, since it is hard to diagnose the problem off of very limited information.

1) You have not been lifting for a long enough period of time.  After two months of lifting, you "might" notice changes in your body, assuming you have been doing some other things correctly (such as the following).

2) Not lifting enough weight.  Is lifting extremely easy when you do it?  Do you lift for 5 minutes a day or 90 minutes?  You said you lift light, well, light might not be working for you if your goal is to gain muscle.

3) Not eating enough calories.  I am doubtful of this one, simply because the previous comments are more plausible, but if you do not consume enough calories, you'll have difficulties gaining much muscle.

Hope this helps... edit your question and provide details if you seek a more specific answer.

Comment: The typical indian diet also really lacks protein, which is essential for recovery and gaining muscle.

Comment: One might claim that about vegan diets too, and yet, vegan heavyweight lifters exist.  If the original poster isn't seeing any results at all, I'd suggest to him to focus on the calorie aspect first and foremost, and begin messing with protein/carb/fat ratios next.  Overall though I believe we have gotten the theme across - eating "correctly" is a key aspect to gaining muscle.

Comment: Yeah but they really watch their macros and take protein supplements or stack up on protein-rich vegetables. Doesn't sound like the poster does that.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional indian diet means carb-loaded with a lack of protein, at least from what I've experienced of Indian cuisine.

Your macros are likely not good with such a diet. You have to adapt.

It's 90% diet and 10% what you do in the gym.

Comment: I need to change my diet hh.