# Training program to get muscles mass

Tags: workout-routines, muscle-mass, workout-types, bulking

I was reading the accepted answer of [What are the trade-offs of weight versus repetition?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/8238/what-are-the-trade-offs-of-weight-versus-repetition/8239#8239) in which the user add this picture:

[image]

However I get  surprised by the training tips given.  According to the picture, to get mass muscle you should practice at least five times a week  ! do 4 to 8 sets with 6 to 12 repetition.

**Questions** : Are those tips  in the picture correct (scientifically ) ? What about the rest days that plays an important role in building muscles ? On the other hand, if this is not the convenient training way, what is the optimal sets-reps programs  in order to get muscles mass ,  and how many times should one practice a week ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Are those tips in the picture correct (scientifically ) ?

Yes, they still hold true.

## What about the rest days that plays an important role in building muscles ?

Rest days are when your muscle mostly does its growing(/repairing)

## On the other hand, if this is not the convenient training way, what is the optimal sets-reps programs in order to get muscles mass , and how many times should one practice a week ?

Depends on you, your goals and your movements. If you are focusing on building mass then more volume (5-6 days a week) traditionally is popular. For those training strength, 3-4 times a week is popular. Avoid training 7 days a week, you need to rest at least 1 day.

Comment: Another thing ,optimal reps depend on you,if you have a higher ratio of fast-twitch muscle fibers ,higher ratio of slow-twitch muscle fibers or you have a balance between both.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however still have ambiguity, if we practice  5-6 days a week, then we will have only two or one day rest, is this enough  for growing the muscle  ?

Comment: Depends on how you are training and how you are refuelling.